# Find maximum with limited length in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for maximum absolute value out of chunked list.

For example, the list is:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 6, -9, 6, 4, 2, 7, 8]
```

I want to find the maximum with lookahead = 4. For this case, it will return me:

```
[5, 7, 9, 8]
```

How can I do simply in Python?

```
for d in data[::4]:
    if count < LIMIT:
        count = count + 1

        if abs(d) > maximum_item:
            maximum_item = abs(d)
    else:
        max_array.append(maximum_item)

        if maximum_item > highest_line:
            highest_line = maximum_item

        maximum_item = 0
        count = 1
```

I know I can use for loop to check this. But I'm sure there is an easier way in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using standard Python:

```
[max(abs(x) for x in arr[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(arr), 4)]
```

This works also if the array cannot be evenly divided.

Comment: what if the array cannot be evenly divided?

Comment: @AlexBelyaev - sorry for not mentioning your comment. The extended numpy solution (with padding) was longer and took more time than this standard Python solution, so I removed it. Please remove your JQuery comment now.

Answer (score 4):

Map the `list` to `abs()`, then [chunk the `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) and send it to `max()`:

```
array = [1,2,4,5,4,5,6,7,2,6,-9,6,4,2,7,8]
array = [abs(item) for item in array]
# use linked question's answer to chunk
# array = [[1,2,4,5], [4,5,6,7], [2,6,9,6], [4,2,7,8]] # chunked abs()'ed list
values = [max(item) for item in array]
```

Result:

```
>>> values
[5, 7, 9, 8]
```

Comment: Is the OP trying to look for max value for each chunk of 4 element?...is that what he means by lookahead =4 ...because I didn't understand him...

Comment: I think they just didn't know the term for it (they've edited it into their question now).

Comment: Answer with numpy is ok, but your is ALOT more educative (thanks for the link):)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, is to use `islice` method from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice) module:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [max(islice(map(abs,array),i,i+4)) for i in range(0,len(array),4)]
[5, 7, 9, 8]
```

To break it down:

1 - `map(abs, array)` returns a list of all absolute values of array elemets 
2 - `islice(map(abs,array),i,i+4))` slices the array in chunks of four elements 
3 - `i in range(0,len(array),4)` stepping range for `islice` to avoid overlapping

This can be wrapped in function as fellows:

```
def max_of_chunks(lst, chunk_size):
    lst = map(abs, lst)
    result = [max(islice(lst,i,i+chunk_size)) for i in range(0,len(lst),chunk_size)]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

**Upd:** Oh, I've just seen newest comments to task and answers. I wasn't get task properly, my bad :) Let my old answer stay here for history. Max numbers from list chunks you can find in the way like that:

```
largest = [max(abs(x) for x in l[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(0, len(l), n)]
```

or

```
largest = [max(abs(x) for x in l[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

if you're use Python3.

---

**Original answer just for history:** If you had to choice some numbers (once) from not a big list, you shouldn't install big libraries like `numpy` for such simple tasks. There are a lot of techniques to do it with built-in Python tools. Here they are (something of them).

So we have some list and count of maximum different elements:

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 6, -9, 6, 4, 2, 7, 8]
In [2]: n = 4
```

**A.** First we getting only unique numbers from source list by converting it to **set**. Then we creating a **list** consist of these unique numbers, **sort** it and finally **get N** last (greatest) elements:

```
In [3]: sorted(list(set(l)))[-n:]
Out[3]: [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**B.** You can use built-in `heapq` module:

```
In [7]: import heapq

In [8]: heapq.nlargest(n, set(l))
Out[8]: [8, 7, 6, 5]
```

Of course you can 'wrap' A or B technique into some human-friendly function like `def get_largest(seq, n): return sorted(list(set(l)))[-n:]`. Yes I've ommited some details like handling `IndexError`. You should remember about it when you'll writing the code.

**C.** If your list(s) is very long and you had to do many of these operations so fast as Python can, you should use special third-party libraries like `numpy` or `bottleneck`.